# Selecting two rows in a table which have the same data for a particular column

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column in a table(contracts) called service location. I have to show all the rows where the service locations matches any other row in the table.

```
    Table Example

 A    B    C
 1    2    3
 3    2    1
 2    5    3
```

I require a query where the first and second rows will be returned based on a comparison on the second column. I am assuming I will need to use a HAVING COUNT(`B`) > 1

I came up with this

```
SELECT  `contract_number` 
FROM  `contracts` 
WHERE  `import_id` =  'fe508764-54a9-41f7-b36e-50ebfd95971b'
GROUP BY  `service_location_id` 
HAVING COUNT(`service_location_id` ) >1
```

But it doesn't generate what I exactly need.

Comment: Your explanation and the example table make me dizzy. Could you please try to correlate what service location is supposed to match up to?

Comment: Remove WHERE  `import_id` =  'fe508764-54a9-41f7-b36e-50ebfd95971b'
from your query and try again with your own solution. Problem can be with your where clause only. otherwise your query is fine and will give the result which you need.

Comment: If two or more rows in the table have the same service location the query should return all those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Having` would do it, but you would need to use it like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Contracts
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  B
            FROM    Contracts
            GROUP BY B
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- MORE THAN ONE ROW WITH THE SAME VALUE
        ) dupe
            ON dupe.B = Contracts.B
```

Depending in your indexing you may find a self join performs better though:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.*
FROM    contracts t1
        INNER JOIN contract` t2
            ON t1.B = t2.B
            AND t1.A <> t2.A
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * 
FROM  `sheet1` 
WHERE  `C` 
IN (

SELECT  `C` 
FROM  `sheet1` 
GROUP BY  `C` 
HAVING COUNT( `C` ) >1
)
ORDER BY  `C` 
LIMIT 0 , 5000